# Parameters through onclick event in asp

Tags: asp.net, onclick, parameter-passing

I've been trying to pass parameters through the onclick event using asp as follows:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdateFacturaID" style="display:none;" onclick="btnUpdateFacturaID_Click" CommandArgument="test" />
```

And on the other side:

```
protected void btnUpdateFacturaID_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string s = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
}
```

But I receive an error of no overload for 'btnUpdateFacturaID_Click' mathes delegate 'System.EventHandler'

In fact, I had initially the functions as follows:

```
protected void btnUpdateFacturaID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
}
```

But this way I can't (or I don't actually know, which is much more probable) pass parameters through the event. What amb I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
protected void btnUpdateFacturaID_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button btn = (Button)sender;
     //do whatever with 
     //btn.CommandArgument.ToString()
}
```

[image]

Comment: that made it. Thank you. (i have to wait some minutes to accept the answer, you were fast! :) )